# Show that well-ordering is not a first-order property.

Tags: proof-writing, compactness, first-order-logic, proof-explanation, higher-order-logic

Problem description: Show that well-ordering is not a first-order notion. Suppose that $\Gamma$ axiomatizes the class of well-orderings. Add countably many constants $c_i$ and show that $\Gamma \cup \{c_{i+1} < c_i \mid i \in \mathcal{N}\}$ has a model.

So, I don’t quite get how to go about this. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937348/why-isnt-there-a-first-order-theory-of-well-order) seems to address the same question, but I don’t understand the answer. I assume I’ll start something like this:

Suppose that $\Gamma$ axiomatizes the class of well-orderings (do I need to define this class?). Let $\{c_i \mid i \in \mathcal{N}\}$ be a set of new constants. Consider the set $A = \Gamma \cup \{c_{i+1} < c_i \mid i \in \mathcal{N}\}$.

And here I can’t quite see how to proceed. How do I show that every finite subset $A_0 \subseteq A$ is satisfiable?

Anyway, suppose I manage to do the above. Then I use compactness to show that $A$ is satisfiable, i.e. $A$ has a model.

Then what? How do I finish it? Or if it is finished, how to I explain that it is?

I should add: hints only, no direct answers — stop me if I’m asking questions that aren’t possible to answer without revealing the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Technically, you let $\{c_{i}\}$ be the set of constants. Then use the fact that a well-ordering has no infinite decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Re: your second question: let $\mathcal{M}$ be a model of $A$. $\mathcal{M}$ is a linear order with a bunch of named elements (the $c_i$s); we can consider the "underlying linear order" $\mathcal{L}$ of $\mathcal{M}$.

- Is $\mathcal{L}$ a well-order?
- Why is that a problem?

Re: your first question, it might be easier to consider a concrete example: can you find a well-ordering with two elements $c_1>c_2$? How about three elements $c_1>c_2>c_3$? How about an arbitrary finite number?

Comment: What do you mean by “underlying linear order”? I’m not very familiar with set theory.

Comment: Ok, so what about this: 

Suppose that for an arbitrary $n \in \mathcal{N}$, $A_n = \Gamma \cup \{c_1 > c_2 > ... > c_n \}$. Then $A_n \subseteq A$. Then every $A_n$ has a least element $c_n$ and is well-ordered, so every finite $A_n$ is satisfiable. 

Something like that? Am I skipping a step; missing something?

Comment: @hsherl It's not quite correct to say e.g. that $A_n$ has a least element, or is well-ordered: $A_n$ is a set of sentences, not a structure. But there's a natural model corresponding to each $A_n$ - do you see how to build it? (HINT: it will have $n$ elements . . .)

Comment: Hm. I can’t quite grasp how to construct these corresponding models.

Comment: Will the model for each $A_n$ look like this: $\mathfrak{A}_n = \langle A_n, <, \{c_k\}_{k\geq n} \rangle$?

Comment: I meant to write $\mathfrak{A}_n = \langle A, <, \{c_i\mid i \in \{1, 2, ..., n\} \} \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT for your first question: For $k\in\Bbb N$ let $\varphi_k$ be $c_{k+1}<c_k$. If $A_0$ is a finite subset of $A$, $A_0'=A_0\setminus\Gamma$. If $A_0'$ is empty, $A_0$ certainly has a model: pick any well-ordering. If $A_0'\ne\varnothing$, let

$$m=\max\{k\in\Bbb N:\varphi_k\in A_0'\}\;,$$

and construct a model of $A$ whose underlying set is $\{0,\ldots,m\}$.

Comment: Thanks! What does $A_0'=A_0\setminus\Gamma$ mean? Is it equivalent to $A_0' = A_0 - \Gamma$? I’ve just never seen that symbol before.

Comment: @hsherl: Yes, it’s set difference. It’s a more modern notation.